# Convert URL of an object to its database instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I created an extra function in my View that receives a list with hyperlinked references to some ResourceGroup objects, but I don't know how to convert them to database instances

```
class ResourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Resource.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer

    @action(methods=['put'], detail=True)
    def groups_append(self, request, pk=None):
        instance = self.get_object()
        groups = request.data.get("groups")
        for resource_group in groups:
            instance.groups.add(WHAT_HERE(resource_group))
        instance.save()
        return Response(self.get_serializer(instance, many=False).data)
```

This is the request:

```
PUT    http://.../api/resources/1/groups_append/
```

with body:

```
{"groups": ["http://.../api/resource_groups/1/", ...]}
```

ResourceSerializer:

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ('resource_id', 'object_id', 'type', 'system', 'path', 'groups', 'job_set')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.object_id = validated_data.get('object_id', instance.object_id)
        instance.type = validated_data.get('type', instance.type)
        instance.system = validated_data.get('system', instance.system)
        instance.path = validated_data.get('path', instance.path)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

ResourceGroupSerializer:

```
class ResourceGroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ResourceGroup
        fields = ('resource_group_id', 'label', 'resource_set')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.label = validated_data.get('label', instance.label)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything specific. Show your ResourceSerializer; are you using a hyperlinked serializer for the groups field?

Comment: Please post code as an edit to the question, properly formatted.

Comment: This is the error I get:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'http://.../api/resource_groups/1/'

Comment: I think that "instance.groups.add(...)" takes only ResourceGroup instances or IDs of ResourceGroup objects, not urls

Comment: Why are you overriding `update` at all? You shouldn't need to. What happens if you remove that method?

Comment: I had some code for updating resource_set, job_set, and other one-to-many or many-to-many fields, but bulk update is not a good practice in this case, so I want to implement methods for appending and removing objects from those lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `HyperlinkedRelatedField` for groups in `ResourceSerializer` or just create a new serializer for this action(the main idea is to get the data using a serializers not just directly from the request body) like this:

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    groups = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='groups-detail' ## name of the groups detail url
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
    ....
```

then edit your action as below:

```
@action(methods=['put'], detail=True)
def groups_append(self, request, pk=None):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    ### then get the groups from the validated data
    groups = serializer.validated_data.get('groups', [])
    ....
    ....
```

References:

1- [hyperlinkedrelatedfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield)